# Setting VBA Excel Chart Legend Position Property in MS Access not working

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

This is a very strange issue I am facing for a while now, when creating some Excel worksheets programmatically from MS Access 2003.

Using this VBA-Code snippet I am not able to set the **Position** property of an Excel's **Legend** object (variable definitions and so on are left out to ease understanding).

```
...
Set ChartObject = myWorksheet.ChartObjects.Add(myRange.Left, myRange.Top, myRange.width, myRange.Height)
Set Chart = ChartObject.Chart
Chart.HasLegend = True
'This line raises an error:
Chart.Legend.Position = -4107 '=xlLegendPositionBottom
...
```

MS Access always raises the Error 1004:

> "Unable to set the Position property of the Legend class"

It confuses me that I can use the exact same code from within Exel VBA and it just works. What confuses me even more is that the property **HasLegend** can be set whithout any error ocurring.

Someone has a hint to solve this issue?

Comment: This worked for me after a fashion in that the syntax for `Set ChartObject = ...` had to be changed (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb148425(v=office.12).aspx). The legend part worked fine.

Comment: Do you mean I should write `Set ChartObject = myWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").ChartObjects.Add(myRange,myRange.Top,myRange.Widht,myRange.height)` to reference the ChartObject?

Comment: I assumed that myrange was a worksheet range, so the first item, myRange is a mismatched type, it needs, say, `myRange.Left`, to get a numeric value.

Comment: @Remou My snippet had a spelling error: The ChartObject syntax is correct. My actual problem is the Position Property.

Comment: Okay, so then the code works for me. What versions(s) are you using? Is there any other code that could be interfering?

Comment: My Version is Office 2003 latest SPs and Patches. Well I am generating a lot of Excel Worksheets and the Position property never worked for me in any of them. The Excel Worksheet is actually generated in an Access class module.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4269/discussion-between-benjamin-brauer-and-remou)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After building a generic version of my code I found that in Office/Excel 2003 I have to populate my Series of data to the chart before changing the Legend's position. Probably the object hasn't been initiated before. My Code should therefore look like this:

```
...
Set ChartObject = myWorksheet.ChartObjects.Add(myRange.Left, myRange.Top, myRange.width,  myRange.Height)
Set Chart = ChartObject.Chart
Chart.HasLegend = True
...
Chart.SeriesCollection.Add myRange, 1 '=xlRows
'Now this works:
Chart.Legend.Position = -4107 '=xlLegendPositionBottom
```